# How can i change the position of a cluster marker in google maps and select individual markers that go inside it?

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

I am trying to cluster specific markers from a set of markers on google maps.
How can I create 2 different clusters that are not based on the distance but data that i have on them?

Example: I have A,B,C markers on UK and A,B,C markers around Europe.
On a high enough zoom level I would like to cluster only A markers and put the cluster marker on London.

Comment: You can try MarkerManager v3 http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/reference.html